# Stochastic Block Model Priors

Tags: bayesian, prior, intuition, model-based-clustering, uninformative-prior

In the generic stochastic block model (binary edge data, no degree correction, etc.), if an uninformed prior is used for the Bernoulli coefficients i.e. Beta with $(a,b) = (1,1)$, will the model converge to a block structure?

That is, if there's no prior on the structure of the graph, will we have "clusters" in the end?

My intuition is no. I have found a paper that uses such a prior and suggests yes.

Comment: Hi Dan and welcome to CV! I suggest you briefly describe what a blockmodel is. May you also link the paper? A blockmodel with a non-informative prior will usually infer the structure (if there is such). Why shouldn't it?

Comment: Hi @alberto thanks for the welcome and response. [Here](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3578-mixed-membership-stochastic-blockmodels.pdf)'s one paper, though SBM's have a very large number of variants.


I will edit the post to describe the model. Intuitively though, the model is trying to encode the notion that a network will have clusters, where each cluster is more connected with the other nodes in the cluster than the nodes not in the cluster. However, with an uninformative prior, the structure need not have higher connections inside than out...

Comment: Sorry, I'm familiar with SBMs but I don't follow you here. Don't they use a non-informative prior? If you pick a random graph with no cluster structure you would probably get no clusters (that is, the posterior is higher when all $z=1$) (my guess)

Comment: @alberto thanks again for responding.

For the block structure, if you were to use a non-informative prior then I don't see why there would be clusters with high in-degree. But [this](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0117179) paper claims to use such a prior, but present results with clear clusters.

Comment: A prior is just your initial guess and it can, and will, be updated through the likelihood: p(clusters | params) x prior(params) If you have enough data, the prior contributes less to the result (is that clear?). Be it informative or not, it does not matter much if you have all the data in the world.

Comment: Another way to think of priors is as regularization factors. They penalize some solutions, but in the end it is the data who will speak (unless you have almost no data; then it will be the prior who speaks)

Comment: Hmmm ok, so if the data were clustered anyway, their results are believable? (I had previously thought they forgot to provide their prior on the diagonal of the block interaction matrix).

Comment: Well, they should check the results whatever prior you use. But if you used a non-informative prior when you have no previous knowledge, then you are less suspicious. At least it does not harm, you are being more honest.